# Nav list item auto size

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have written this script with the help from some members on here (thanks for that) that gets the width of a nav, and all its list item children, works out how much space there is free and sets that as padding for each anchor in the list item. It works but im out by about 2 pixels per padding and not sure where i have gone wrong. anyone got any clues?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var numb = $("nav ul").children().length,
        nav = $('nav').outerWidth(),
        width = 0;

    $('nav ul li').each(function () {
        width += $(this).outerWidth();
    });

    var padding = ((nav - width) / numb) / 2;

    $('nav ul li a').css({
        'padding-right': padding,
        'padding-left': padding,
    });
});
```

here is a working/non working js fiddle of the issue http://jsfiddle.net/axXR4/

thanks!

Comment: The padding being calculated in my browser is 31.5px. It may be that different browsers make different decisions about what to do with those half pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two changes are needed.

First, drop the decimal from your padding value:

```
var padding = Math.floor(((nav - width) / numb) / 2);
```

And remove the padding from  your `ul`:

```
nav ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/axXR4/5/